# Enforcement of returning non-null

Tags: c#, contract, aspect-oriented

We are implementing some web services, and need to ensure that some of our methods **always** return non-null values.

We've investigated two ways of doing this:

- Using [code contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx), and returning the default value using `Ensures`  constraints on the return value.
- Using an [aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) approach using [PostSharp](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorony/archive/2007/01/29/Using-AOP-and-PostSharp-to-Enhance-Your-Code_3A00_-Part-A.aspx).

Both approaches work, but I'm wondering whether there are any other approaches that we should consider.

How would you enforce non-null return values?

---

[Looks like there was a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291340/mark-parameters-as-not-nullable-in-c-net), and Jon Skeet recommends the Code Contract approach.

Comment: It's been years sice I've used C# seriously at all, but why would you need to enforce returning non-null values? Generally, `null` is a perfectly valid return value.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to ensure that null is never possibly returned, or a way to enforce that null return values are treated as runtime errors?

Comment: @Demian: `null` is certainly a valid value for objects. The trouble is that, we want to completely avoid `System.NullReferenceException`s in the receivers of the `null`.

Comment: @Kevin: The former: `null` is never possibly returned.

Comment: Providing you have the tooling available I would definitely go with code contracts. You can then use static analysis to find/eliminate possible null references - pretty much any other approach will only help you at runtime (and obviously contracts will give you that too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be 100% certain that there will always be a valid value to return, then the code contracts method makes perfect sense, and you can go on your way.

Now, if there is a possibility of a situation where the method might not have a valid value to return, then you can *still* use the code contract method and implement the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). The issue with the pattern is that you still have to, kind of, check for null but the client will never get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Thanks! That gives an interesting addition we hadn't thought about.